# Datomic Transaction Functions on Every Transaction

Tags: clojure, datomic

Is there a way to append a transaction function to every transaction before it is committed in datomic? For example, regardless of the source of the transaction, we want to invalidate a record.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "append" or rather call a transaction function before a transaction is committed. The transaction processor will lookup the function in its :db/fn attribute and then invoke it, passing the value of the db (currently as of the beginning of the transaction).  As such you will need to make the call before each transaction.

Please note there is no api or flow from transaction function to automatically call a transactor function on each transact call.  For every call to transact you will need to call your validating transactor function.

http://docs.datomic.com/database-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the incoming transaction data, you can do some trickery on the peer side to validate it. For example, you can take a db, use `with` to get a "fake" db with the incoming transaction applied, and then validate based on that db. For example, you can easily get which entities that were touched based in this transaction, using the normal Datomic APIs on this "fake" db from `with`, and see if the incoming transaction touched entities that it was not allowed to touch.

If however you want to validate something on the transactor side, your only option is manually invoking database functions.